# Gluing two pieces of glass together - type of glue, techniques

Tags: adhesive, glass, laminate

I am trying to laminate together two sheets of glass of 6mm (~ 1/4") in order to have a thicker glass plate that will serve as a backing plate for sandpaper in order to flatten stuff (sole of hand planes etc.)

What would be the best glue to use and are there significant tips on how to best achieve this glue-up?

Comment: Just buy a scrap of thicker plate glass, or granite countertop scrap. If you glue two thinner sheets together, you have to make sure that the two rather more flexible sheets do not bend during gluing and yield a non-flat result.

Comment: Go to your local scrapyard, and buy a flat piece of car window glass - flat, and a lot safer!

Comment: Not all car window glass is flat @Tim. Do be sure to bring a straight edge to make sure you get something that actually _is_ flat.

Comment: I'd like to introduce you to [Woodworking.se]. If you care enough to flatten your hand planes, you'll definitely want to stop by there! _Loads_ of great info.

Comment: @FreeMan - Well aware of that. That's why I used the word - *flat*. Wouldn't be valid otherwise! Still a better bet than the original idea... However, I find that the surface of any of my benches is flat enough by itself not to need any of that palaver.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: That was my initial plan but the very few glass shops that still exist only sold me 6mm (1/4") thick glass. This is how I ended up doing more work and probably achieving a less quality result. Sorry, I can't find (even scrap) thick glass around...

Comment: Tim, FreeMan : Indeed car glass is almost always curved, be it windshield, door glass etc... I look at my car (VW Tiguan 2009), none of its 12 pieces of glass is flat..

Comment: @FreeMan: Thank you for introducing the woodworking site of SE, I was already a member (check out my profile) but I considered this post better suited here than there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest just using a thin layer of silicone sealant.  Once in place, it will be almost impossible to separate the sheets of glass again.  Just make sure your glass is clean and dry before gluing together.

Comment: Silicone holds aquariums together pretty well.

Comment: @Milwrdfan: regular silicone sealant woulnd't it be a little thick? Would it be better than CA glue (such as "superglue" and other commercial names)?

Comment: @AndreiRînea, you'd probably want to spread on a very thin layer very smoothly, and then weight the two pieces together.  I'd be concerned that CA adhesive wouldn't be able to get good adherence to a smooth glass surface.